# Request to undelete one of two duplicate answers

Tags: support, moderation, specific-answer, vote-to-undelete

I wrote the same answer to two different questions that were essentially duplicates of each other. It turns out that I should have just answered one of them and then marked the other question as a duplicate of the first.

- [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167811/how-to-use-datajpatest-with-multiple-datasourse/50183828?noredirect=1#comment87386840_50183828)
- [Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325705/using-datajpatest-when-multiple-datasources-are-configured/50183823?noredirect=1#comment87386841_50183823)

However, I cannot mark the second question as duplicate of the first question until the first question has an upvoted or accepted answer. Well, my answer was the first answer, but a moderator deleted my answer to *both* questions.

Could I get someone to undelete [my answer on this (the first) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167811/how-to-use-datajpatest-with-multiple-datasourse/50183828?noredirect=1#comment87386840_50183828)?

Comment: let's talk the moderator who did this : @SamuelLiew

Comment: @Temani that won't ping anyone....

Comment: @Patrice really? why ?

Comment: @Temani Samuel has had no interactions with this post. You can't @ anyone and have the system ping them. They have to have done something on the post (comment, edit, close voted). Imagine how many OP would ping our top users if this was a feature

Comment: @Patrice true, I remember did this before but maybe it was a coincidence ...

Comment: @Temani oh it can happen for sure(just like it did here actually). But it's not because the user got pinged.

Comment: I just happened to be on Meta at the moment. You can ping me by commenting on any of my posts on Meta, or inviting me into a chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, your post on [how to use @DataJpaTest with multiple datasourse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167811/how-to-use-datajpatest-with-multiple-datasourse) is undeleted.

As you have duplicate answers on these questions, I've marked them as a duplicate of the above:

- [Using @DataJpaTest when multiple datasources are configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325705/using-datajpatest-when-multiple-datasources-are-configured)
- [Using @DataJpaTest with multiple DataSource and custom repository implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471969/using-datajpatest-with-multiple-datasource-and-custom-repository-implementation)